# Disconnect the already loaded webpage(uses socket.io) before loading the new url in WebView

Tags: android, webview, socket.io, android-webview, socket.io-1.0

The WebView loads a webpage which uses socket.io

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
myWebView.loadUrl(socket_io_page_url);
```

The session is maintained using cookies. When the android logout action item is activated the cookies must be cleared and a new url is loaded as shown in the following code

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookie();
myWebView.loadUrl(new_url);
```

This works but the connection to the previous url(socket_io_page_url) is not terminated immediately. Since the WebView does not support web sockets, the long-polling is used by the webview and it waits about 20 seconds to disconnect the previous url. The time out can be changed, but it will be a very bandwidth costly operation.

At this point it is not possible to switch to native java coding. So disconnecting the previous connection is very important to the application. I tried

```
myWebView.destroy()
```

---

```
System.gc()** after new url load,
```

---

```
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(false); and setting back
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

---

None of them worked. killing the application using **cleaner** application disconnects the socket immediately. Is there a way to disconnect the previously loaded page.

Comment: On what Android version(s) does this happen?

Comment: android version 4.2.2